# implement my own myless

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am trying to understad how std::less is implemented so I can say

```
template <typename T>
struct myless
{
    constexpr bool operator()(const T &lhs, const T &rhs) const
    {
        return lhs < rhs;
    }
};

template <typename A, typename B, typename U = myless> // std::less works
bool f(A a, B b, U u = U())
{
    return u(a, b);
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;

    std::cout << f("AB/CD", "CD/AB") << '\n';
    std::cout << f(100, 10) << '\n';
}
```

This doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: What `constexpr` is doing there?

Comment: Your code is not even close to be compilable. "This doesn't work." is not helpful, you need to be more specific. If I [fix the obvious errors](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33d84f6e437732b4), it does work.

Comment: @c-smile, `std::less::operator()` has the `constexpr` qualifier in C++14

Comment: I looked into the visual studio's implementation, and it actually has template with 2 and 3 argumnets, and when only 2 are provided, it uses less<>(), otherwise it tries to call the predicate, so in your case U

Comment: Your first example `f("AB/CD", "CD/AB")` is comparing `const char*` pointers

Comment: Don't put stuff in the `std` namespace. It's UB.

Comment: `std::less<T>` isn't that great a design for non-`void` `T`s. It makes a lot more sense to imitate `std::less<void>` - i.e., template the `operator()`, not the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo in `f("AB/CD", "CD/AB",)` (comma).
It should be `typename U = myless<A>` because `myless` is not in the `std` namespace.
Also the parameters should probably be passed by reference: `bool f(const A& a, const B& b, const U& u = U())`.

`std::less` needs both operands to be of the same type (logically), and `myless` is also defined like that. So using `myless<A>` for `U` would make it convert the `B` object to `A` for the comparing (by creating a temporary using its copy-constructor).

Since C++14, there is also the specialization `std::less<void>` where the operand can have different types, and a return type that is not bool. It maps one-to-one to what the `operator<` does. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less_void .

Corrected version of the code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct myless
{
    constexpr bool operator()(const T &lhs, const T &rhs) const
    {
        return lhs < rhs;
    }
};

template <typename A, typename B, typename U = myless<A>>
bool f(const A& a, const B& b, const U& u = U())
{
    return u(a, b);
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;

    std::cout << f("AB/CD", "CD/AB") << '\n';
    std::cout << f(100, 10) << '\n';
}
```

For a version that can have different types, and non-bool return type:

```
struct myless2 {
    template<class T, class U>
    constexpr auto operator()(const T& t, const U& u) const -> decltype(t < u) {
        return t < u;
    }
};
```

`std::less<void>` seems to also support r-value references, for when the `operator<` is defined like that (probably doing something else than comparation then.)

Comment: The provided `f` function can be called like this: `f("test", 3.3)`, which produces a compilation error. I think what you have is fine but shouldn't the 2 arguments of the `f` function enforce that `a` and `b` are of the same type?

Answer (score 2):

Your `myless` template takes a single type but your `f` function takes two types (i.e., they might be different types). It's possible to support this but it's more involved. Did you intend to do the following instead?

```
template<typename T, typename U = myless<T>>
bool f(T a, T b, U u = U())
{
    return u(a, b);
}
```

### Edit

As @vscoftco pointed out supporting different types may have been an intended use case. If different types were to be explicitly supported then I would have implemented it like this.

```
template<typename A, typename B, typename U = myless<typename std::common_type<A, B>::type>>
bool f(A a, B b, U u = U())
{
    return u(a, b);
}
```

It also appears this solution is SFINAE compatible (C++17), http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type.

> If sizeof...(T) is zero or if there is no common type, the member type is not defined (std::common_type is SFINAE-friendly)

Comment: I think the idea to use 2 types is OK, and should compile (provided OP corrects the other typos mentioned). Basically OP allows for convertible types. The function `f` specifically instantiates `myless<A>` (or `myless<B>`), which was the part forgotten by OP, so `myless` is not confused anymore by type deduction.

Comment: @vsoftco Okay, I definitely didn't get that impression from the question. Since they were "trying to understad (sic) how std::less is implemented" and the calls to `f` used the same types.

Comment: that's the smart way to do it, with `std::common_type` :)